# Is it possible to distinguish a study vs. a strategy within a script?

Tags: pine-script

I have a strategy that I periodically switch back to a study. It'd be nice if I could have some logic in the script that allowed me to set a condition to perform certain things if it's a study vs. a strategy.

Is it possible to determine within a script if it's a strategy or a study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done. The closest you can get is by writing hybrid code and flip between study and strategy mode manually by commenting/un-commenting lines. See these 2 examples of hybrid code:

https://www.tradingview.com/script/pjZKWnHl-Volatility-System-by-Wilder-LucF/

https://www.tradingview.com/script/dYqL95JB-Backtesting-Trading-Engine-PineCoders/

When you don't need strategy mode, study mode should be used, as studies run much faster than strategies.